# Code refactor - how to handle different outputs using one method

Tags: java, refactoring

My Repository class that reads and persists data from DB has two methods:

```
public InputStream findXmlResponse(ID id) {
       Entity entity = (Entity) entityManager
                .createQuery("SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.id = :id")
                .setParameter("id", iid)
                .getSingleResult();
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(entity.getReportFile().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

}

public String findXmlResponseDif(ID id) {
        Entityentity = (Entity ) entityManager
                .createQuery("SELECT e FROM Entitye WHERE e.id = :id")
                .setParameter("id", id)
                .getSingleResult();
        return entity.getReportFile();
}
```

I want to create new object ResultObject that will be returned from both of these methods (and instead of two have just one) like this:

```
public ResultObject findXmlResponseUni(ID id) {
            Entity entity = (Entity ) entityManager
                    .createQuery("SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.id = :id")
                    .setParameter("id", id)
                    .getSingleResult();
            return new ResultObject ;
    }
```

I tried:

```
@Getter
public class ResultObject extends InputStream {

    @EJB
    private Repository repository;

    private final String xmlResult;

    public ResultObject() {
        xmlResult = null;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        return 0;
    }


    public InputStream resultAsInput(ID id) {
        InputStream xmlResult = repository.findXmlResponseUni(id);
            return xmlResult;
    }

    public String resultAsString(ID id) {
        String xmlResult = String.valueOf(repository.findXmlResponseUni(id));
        return xmlResult;
    }
}
```

Later I would like to use it in another classes as String :

```
public String pullxml() {
                return String.valueOf(repository.findXmlResponseUni();
```

or as Input:

```
 public Display create(ID id) {
        InputStream xmlResult = repository.findXmlResponseUni(id);
        return prepare(xmlResult);
    }
```

But I've run into several errors while building the project. I wonder where exactly should I apply
      ByteArrayInputStream(entity.getReportFile().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

to convert the returned value into InputStream - in ResultObject or maybe in classes that will use Input as a result? Should ResultObject extend the InputStream? What is the most effective way to use this kind of Object and pass it further?

Comment: Create an object `Entity` which contains the `String` as a field and has a getter for it like `getContent` and another function `getContentAsInputStream` that returns the `String` like you implemented above (I can't deduce better names given your sample code). This allows the user of the function to decide whether to use an `InputStream` or the `String`. But why do you need the two  variants?

Comment: for a roookeee, that was a pretty solid answer 

Comment: I ve created the ResultObject - with field String and two methods that returns InputStream and String separately - You mean I should return a String in method that should return getContentAsInputStream? and where to wrap it as Input Stream according to its name? Should this object extend the InputStream as it does now? Later I have different methods - one need the query result in form of Input Stream and one as String